# Is this set dense in $L^{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a question about function spaces.

For an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, we consider the Sobolev space

$H^{1}(\Omega):=\left\{ u \in L^{2}(\Omega) : D_{j}u \in L^{2}(\Omega), j=1,\ldots,n \right\}$

with norm

$\|u\|^{2}_{H^{1}(\Omega)}:=\|u\|^{2}_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\|D_{j}u\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}$,

where $D_{j}u=\partial u/ \partial x_{j}$ is the distributional deriavtive. Moreover, we let

$\widetilde{H}^{1}(\Omega):=\text{closure of }H^{1}(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})\text{ in }H^{1}(\Omega)\text{ w.r.t. }\|\cdot\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)}$,

where $C(\bar{\Omega})$ denotes the space of all continuous real valued functions on $\bar{\Omega}$ and

$H^{1}(\Omega) \cap C^{1}(\bar{\Omega})=\left\{ u|{}_{\Omega} \in H^{1}(\Omega): u \in C(\bar{\Omega})\right\}.$ (I think this is usual definition)

**Can we show thet $\widetilde{H}^{1}(\Omega)$ is dense subset of $L^{2}(\Omega)$?**

My attempt:

Since $H^{1}(\Omega)$ and $C(\Omega)$ is dense subsets of $L^{2}(\Omega)$, $H^{1}(\Omega)\cap C(\Omega)$ is dense subset of $L^{2}(\Omega)$. Thus $\left(\text{closure of }H^{1}(\Omega) \cap C(\Omega)\text{ in }H^{1}(\Omega)\text{ w.r.t. }\|\cdot\|_{H^{1}(\Omega)} \right)$ is dense subset of $L^{2}(\Omega)$. But I think it is not clear $\widetilde{H}^{1}(\Omega)$ is dense subset of $L^{2}(\Omega)$ because $H^{1}(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega}) \subset H^{1}(\Omega) \cap C(\Omega) $.

If you have a nice idea, please tell me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know that $C^\infty_c(\Omega) \subset C(\bar{\Omega})$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Comment: @sharpe: Note that the density of both $H^1(\Omega)$ and $C(\Omega)$ do not show the density of their intersection. ($\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q} + \pi$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but their intersection is empty)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I understood.